# Call image url into magento admin

Tags: php, image, magento, call, radix

hope you can help me - I seem unable to recall the url needed from the image folder in magento to allow thumbnail images to appear in admin:

```
 $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getproduct_id());
    $html = '<img src="' . Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/product' . $p->getsmall_image() . '" width="50" height="50" alt="' . $p->getname() . '" />';
    return $html;
```

This is the url I get back below:

```
media/catalog/productno_selection
```

does anyone have any ideas how to recall a thumbnail image for example?

Answer (score 0):

if you need image in admin grid

check this url http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-renderer-magento-grid

or

add below column in your grid

```
   …
    $this->addColumn('product_id', array(
    'header' => $this->__('Product'),
                'align'  => 'center',
                'index'  => 'product_id',
                'width'  => '50px',
                'renderer'  => 'Namespace_Module_Block_Product'
    ));
    …
```

Now we will create the block indicated in the parameter **renderer**

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Block_Product extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{  
 public function render(Varien_Object $row)
 {
    $productId =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $value = '<img src="">';
    if($product->getImage()!= 'noselection')
    {
      $value='<img src="' . $product->getImageUrl() . '" width="100" height="100" />';
    }

    return $value;
}
}
```

check below links help you to create custom column in grid

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-renderer-magento-grid

you need to render.

hope this help you

Comment: Please do not copy or theft things and logic from others answrer. you can copy and edit your answer from mine. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions please see this post by meta. please dont do this again.

Comment: can you please give the url from where it copy ? & i clearly mentioned that this logic is from blog post http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-renderer-magento-grid

Comment: you have edited whole answer and copy concept from my answer to make your answer accept. :(

Comment: ha ha great joke liyakat you can check both of our render its totaly different  & i thought you have copied my answer. & i am not posting here for getting reputation. you want this credit than i have not problem. we are not kids. :)

Comment: i dont need any reputation,6.5k+ is enough to put trust on my answer. i think you need it. thats way you have theft my concept and logic. hope moderator are watching on this.

Comment: exactly moderator must watch on this. we are here to help others. let moderator decide this matter

Comment: yes we are help to others, but not copy answer from others. just wait and watch.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but I think I am missing something - this from the grid:

  $this->addColumn('Picture', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Picture'),
            'index' => 'picture',
            'align' => 'center',
            'renderer' => 'MDN_Quotation_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Picture',
            'sortable' => false,
            'filter' => false,
        ));

Comment: this from the file:  public function render(Varien_Object $row) {


       $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getproduct_id());
        $html = '<img src="' . Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/product' . $p->getsmall_image() . '" width="50" height="50" alt="' . $p->getname() . '" />';
        return $html;
  
 
  
    }

Comment: try this  public function render(Varien_Object $row) { 
 $productId =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
 $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); $html = '<img src="' . Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog/product' . $p->getsmall_image() . '" width="50" height="50" alt="' . $p->getname() . '" />'; return $html; }

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom Renderer to show any outside objects in to admin grid

_prepareColumns() function, in Grid.php(path: `code/local/Packagename/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Modulename/Grid.php`).

```
$this->addColumn('modulenameimage', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Image'),
    'align' => 'left',
    'index' => 'modulenameimage',
    'renderer' => 'modulename/adminhtml_modulename_renderer_image',
    'width' => '107'
));
```

and make one extra render file like

```
Packagename_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Modulename_Renderer_Image
```

Add below code to render file

```
class Packagename_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Modulename_Renderer_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {

    public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
        $html = '<img ';="" $html="" .="id="" $this-="">getColumn()->getId() . '" ';
        $html .= 'width="' . $this->getColumn()->getWidth() . '" ';
        $html .= 'src="' . Mage::getBaseUrl("media") . 'images/' . $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()) . '"';
        $html .= 'class="grid-image ' . $this->getColumn()->getInlineCss() . '"/>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

you can specify and height and width as you need.

hope this will sure help you. and let me know if i can help you further.